# How do I implement an async @PostConstruct method in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

How can I implement an async post-construct method in micronaut?
Ie I want to be able to return a Completable or similar from the method and Micronaut should not consider the bean to be initialized until it has completed.

In eg vert.x u get a "callback handle" to signal completeness to, but I have not found anything similar in Micronaut.

BR / Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a reactive type or a completion stage from a post construct method is not supported. Micronaut cannot continue processing until the method returns so I don't see much value in doing so.

Comment: Ok then I know. The use case is when we have a number of beans that all need to do some io to load the initial state, which will be much quicker if it was done in parallell (eg by returning a Completable from each bean)

Comment: @JonasBergström You can mark your beans with `@Parallel` and they will be loaded on startup in another thread

Comment: Ok...hmm, confusing to put it on class level, it should be on the method. Anyways, thanks!